# Using QmessageBox in translated mode causes the first charactor of each sentences go under the messageBox icon

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I use `QMessageBox` to show messages in program(Information, Critical, Warnings and ...). It works well in English but when it is translated to farsi, the first charactors of each sentences will go under the icon.It doesn't happen always and as I understand it just happens when I use .arg for string and in argument part use "\n". for example in following code:

```
QMessageBox::critical(NULL , "Error", QString(tr("Backup creation failed. %1").arg("\nTest")));
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code calling QMessageBox, and post a screenshot showing how the message box looks.

Comment: @ sashoalm : I test it more. It doesn't happen always and as I understand it just happens when I use .arg for string and in argument part use "\n". for example in following cod: 'QMessageBox::critical(NULL , "Error", QString(tr("Backup creation failed. %1").arg("\nTest")));'

Comment: the image links are: http://i.imgur.com/09dl6Ue.png and http://i.imgur.com/uYGnXC9.png

Comment: In the link with Farsi the text does not go under the icon, it is right of the icon. So there is no problem it seems?

Comment: @ sashoalm : Thanks for the edition.No it is incorrect. the first charactor is incompleted.It is تولید and as you see it is not correct. I thought the icon have white background and the charactor goes under the background.

Comment: But there is no text below the icon. The text is only to the left of the icon.

Comment: So what is the problem that make charactor incompleted?